# Ternary if in Javascript with function

Tags: javascript, function, ternary-operator

I would like to write a ternary if statement in javascript where you call a function and if it returns a value other then 0 set the variable to that value otherwise set it to something else
ex:

```
selectedStartDate = (GetURLParameter("StartDate")) ? 
                     GetURLParameter("StartDate") : 
                     $("#start_date").val();
```

Is there a way to get rid of the double function call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
selectedStartDate = GetURLParameter("StartDate") || $("#start_date").val();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
selectedStartDate = GetURLParameter("StartDate") || $("#start_date").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getURLParam = GetURLParameter("StartDate");    
selectedStartDate = (getURLParam ) ? getURLParam  : $("#start_date").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do something like this:

```
var urlParameter = GetURLParameter("StartDate");
selectedStartDate = urlParameter ? urlParameter : $("#start_date").val();
```